# Can we connector to Azure AD using a nodejs protocol based library

Tags: azure-active-directory, ldap, ldapjs

We are planning to integrate with Azure AD and have explored Graph API.

We were thinking if we can connect to Azure AD using a protocol based implementation something like this.

http://ldapjs.org/client.html

```
const ldap = require('ldapjs');

const client = ldap.createClient({
url: ['ldap://127.0.0.1:1389', 'ldap://127.0.0.2:1389']
});

client.on('error', (err) => {
// handle connection error
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Found one MS document that can help to integrate your node.js application to  with Azure AD using the authorization code flow

a Node.js web app can sign in users by using the authorization code flow. The code sample also demonstrates how to get an access token to call Microsoft Graph API.

Would Request you to go through this MS document to get it addressed : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-nodejs-webapp-msal

Comment: thanks a log Rahul, I tried this and this just take care of token generation part. We were looking for migrating data from on premise active directory to azure.